# Regular expression for validating Date format ddmmyy

Tags: asp.net

I need regular expression for validating the date format **ddmmyy**.

Comment: Looks like Lawrence already nailed it down below.  But do you have to use a regular expression to check if it's a valid date?  You can use DateTime.TryParse() in about two or three lines and get your answer right there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx and then if you need it to be in a certain format, you can use DateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") or whatever format is necessary.

Comment: Please update us if you found a solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

K, I'm going to go ahead and assume you also need to validate that it is a valid date. So... do this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtDate" runat="server" MaxLength="6" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate" OnServerValidate="validate_Date" ErrorMessage="Invalid (ddmmyy)" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void validate_Date(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rDate = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^(?<day>[0-9]{2})(?<mon>[0-9]{2})(?<year>[0-9]{2})");
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = rDate.Match(args.Value);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        //Now try parse as a date
        DateTime dtCheck = DateTime.MinValue;
        args.IsValid = DateTime.TryParse(String.Format("20{0}-{1}-{2}", m.Groups["year"].Value, m.Groups["mon"].Value, m.Groups["year"].Value), out dtCheck);
    }
}
```

Comment: i need regular expression for ddmmyy i tried using ^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(19|20) when my entered date is 121012 showing error pls help me.

Comment: That's an awful way to validate a date. Please don't do that.